# observablecollection memory usage issue

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

if large amount of data fetched from database to observable collection it hangs the application while rendering the data. can we implement data virtualization technique in observable collection

[got an example of data virtualization here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization)

but it directly bind data to Datacontest in code behind. here i am using WPF (MVVM). so how to implement the technique in my case.

Thanks & regards

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve your question. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) including the link "How to ask questions the smart way."

Comment: @zhon Thanks for the advise. replay me if you know the solution or technologies mentioned above. peoples understood the question and answered as i expected. Once again thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

In the past I already had this problem too. My solution was not to directly push the items to the `ObservableCollection`. Instead I've startet a `DispatcherTimer` with an interval of 150 milliseconds. On each tick of the timer I've added a certain amount of items from the fetched-records to the `ObserableCollection`

Comment: can you please share the code section to konw how you implemented that